# Trying to resolve a merge conflict involving a deleted file

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

This is the message I am getting

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): 
labs/lab14_observer_gui/new_code/web_code/web/my_web_server_command.cc deleted in HEAD and 
modified in f42855bbf7dab5122732e1af3e48808d86bd9f71. Version 
f42855bbf7dab5122732e1af3e48808d86bd9f71 of 
labs/lab14_observer_gui/new_code/web_code/web/my_web_server_command.cc left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I the past I have been able to resolve conflicts by going into the file and making the necessary changes, but when I go to the file here I don't see the diff between HEAD and the changes.

Comment: There cannot be merge conflict markers if one side deleted the file. Instead, the version of the other side is left. Now you have to decide how you salvage the changes that side made, or whether you delete the file.

Comment: No need to show you HEAD.... in HEAD the file is gone. So the file was modified on the other branch. How did it change? Do you need to move that change to another place? Or it's ok to remove it? If it's ok to remove it then run `git rm the-file`. If you need to bring the file back from the dead just run `git add the-file`.

Comment: removing the file resolved the conflict. thanks.